# .htaccess RewriteRule for URL in iframe src attribute

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iframe

I have multiple environments for a site, and each time Production is copied to Test or Dev I end up getting URLs for Prod in the Test and Dev environments. One of the URLs a login inside of an iframe to an external application. What I'm hoping to do is create an htaccess `RewriteRule` that will allow me to change the iframe `src=""` attribute in the Dev and Test sites in case the Prod URL gets copied down. Here's what I have tried so far:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)app\.mydomain\.com(.+) https://dev-app.mydomain.com$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

My `RewriteCond` check does validate, so the `RewriteRule` should execute, but the iframe src attribute does not get rewritten to the dev-app subdomain.

For some additional info, the iframe src was initially written with JS in a document ready statement. The rewrite did not work with that, so I hardcoded the iframe src into the actual src attribute, and it still isn't being rewritten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that won't be possible to do from `dev` domain because your iframe URL is going to `app.mydomain.com` so only a rule that exists on `app.mydomain.com` host can redirect it back to your `dev` domain.

Rewrite rules can only redirect a URL once it reaches to a web server, it cannot change your HTML source.

Comment: Would this carry along any query string params?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be working. The iframe src attribute is still `app.` instead of `dev-app.` after applying the rewrite rule.

Comment: `https://app.mydomain.com/Account/TrialRegistrationCms?style=cms-static-header-form&script=cms-static-header-form&mediacode=&device=c&package=&noCache=59849918727961`

Comment: The only thing that would need to change is the subdomain part. It needs to be `dev-app.` instead of `app.` Then there is a test environment too, which needs to be `test-app.`.

Comment: ok first verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158016/discussion-between-andywarren-and-anubhava).